# results are appended into iframe every invocation

Tags: html, iframe, flickr

I have an iframe that displays thumbnail images from Flickr in my web application. The problem, I see is when I reload the page, sometimes, I see the same set of images being appended to the earlier set of images. So I get two sets of every image and on a subsequent reload, I get 3 sets of images.

The images are part of a form. So I see multiple submit and cancel buttons as well. Any suggestions on what might be causing this and how I can avoid this from happening?

Comment: Can we see your code? What browser(s) are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Pardon my ignorance. I was not resetting my server side variable after the fetch and hence I was seeing the above weirdness. Firebug helped me debug this.